# Using a session variable between classes after login - null object reference

Tags: java, android, sqlite, session

I have created an app where you can login using SQLite and it checks the database for matching users.

I have got the login working and I've got it to set a boolean variable to true once the user has logged in, but I am trying to figure out how to pass it back to **MainActivity.java** from **Login.java** in the **onResume()** method.

Here is the code from **Login.java**, I set the session to true then I use **putExtra** to send it back to MainActivity.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                String username = usernameET.getText().toString();
                String password = passwordET.getText().toString();  
                boolean success = db.Login(username, password);       

                if(success)
                {
                    Log.d("login", "user logged");                  
                    session = true;                     
                    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("loginSuccess", session);
                    i.putExtra("sessionName", username);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d("login", "user not logged");
                }
            }
```

And here is the code from **MainActivity.java** in the **onResume()** method. The if statement is where the error is, I just want to know how I can get my application to recognise the boolean so it knows the user is logged in when returning the the main page, and stores the users name so that I can then load the user's information depending on who is logged in.

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onRestart();
    Log.d("On Restart", "ON RESTART CALLED");
    boolean sessionBool = false;
    if (sessionBool = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("loginSuccess"))
    {
        sessionBool = true;
        String sessionNamestring = getIntent().getStringExtra("sessionName");
        Log.d("Session Name", sessionNamestring);

    }
    else
    {
        sessionBool = false;
    }
```

**Logcat**

```
02-21 00:54:29.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2563): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 00:54:29.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2563): Process: com.example.project, PID: 2563
02-21 00:54:29.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2563): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.project/com.example.project.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Bundle.getBoolean(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
02-21 00:54:29.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2989)
02-21 00:54:29.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3020)
02-21 00:54:29.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
02-21 00:54:29.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
02-21 00:54:29.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
02-21 00:54:29.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-21 00:54:29.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-21 00:54:29.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
02-21 00:54:29.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-21 00:54:29.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-21 00:54:29.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
02-21 00:54:29.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
02-21 00:54:29.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2563): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Bundle.getBoolean(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
02-21 00:54:29.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at com.example.project.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:64)
02-21 00:54:29.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1257)
02-21 00:54:29.174: E/AndroidRuntime(2563):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6076)
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you need to use this session in another activity! You will need to send it by extra again! So, I recommend to use [sharedprefrences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) and store your credential(session) and wherever you, Get a session from shared and use it

Answer (score 1):

The extras you are looking for will not be there if your `MainActivity` has been started by the launcher. You need to restructure you logic to something like:

```
final Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.hasExtra("loginSuccess")) {
    final loginSuccess = intent.getBooleanExtra("loginSuccess", false);
    // proceed with your logic, based on the extracted value
}
```

That way you won't try and access the intent extras, if they are not set, avoiding the NPE.

A few other suggestions:

- If your `MainActivity` is starting `Login`, and then `Login` is sending information back to the `MainActivity`, you may want to consider using `startActivityForResult()`
- When you pass data through intent extras, it's better to extract the keys as constants and reference them, instead of hardcoding them. It's a better coding practice and saves you from potentially nasty errors.

Comment: Thankyou, this does make a lot more sense. However when I use getBooleanExtra it says "The method getBooleanExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Comment: @MattMurphy That's my bad. The method `getBooleanExtra()` requires you to pass in the default value you want to receive in case the extra has not been set. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you calling super.onRestart() in your onResume()? Since you're calling this method there won't be an extra which is why you're getting a nullpointer. Change the super.onRestart() line to super.onResume().

Also, depending on your situation you might want to store the boolean in the sharedpreferences instead of passing it back and forth between your activities.